# Testing a subspace for closure under addition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Determine whether the following subsets of $V$ are subspaces of $V$.  Justify your answers: if the subset is a subspace, verify the necessary properties a subspace must have; if it is not a subspace, show at least one required property which fails.

$W = \left\{ \left(t-s, 2t+s\right): s,t \in R \right\}, V= R^2$

So far i've done the following:

$u=\left(u_2-u_1, 2u_2 +u_1\right)$

$v=\left(v_2-v_1, 2v_2 +v_1\right)$

Adding $u+v$ I got the following:

$\left(u_2-u_1\right)+\left(v_2-v_1\right), \left(2u_2+u_1\right)+\left(2v_2+v_1\right)$

$\left(u_2+v_2, -u_1-v_1\right), \left(2u_2+2v_2, u_1+v_1\right)$

$\left(v_2-v_1, u_2-u_1\right), \left(2v_2+v_1, 2u_2+u_1\right)$

Which I believe is in $V$.  I'm wondering if I tested for closure under addition properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you confused yourself writing $u+v$ - and, when you say "which i believe is in $V$", you don't give a proper justification of it.

$$u+v = (u_2-u_1, 2u_2 + u_1) + (v_2-v_1, 2v_2+v_1) $$

$$= (u_2-u_1 + v_2 - v_1, 2u_2 + u_1 + 2v_2 + v_1)$$

$$= (u_2 + v_2 - (u_1 + v_1), 2(u_2+v_2) + (u_1 + v_1))$$

If you put $t= u_2+v_2$, $s= u_1+v_1$ then you have $u+v = (t-s, 2t + s)$. So $u+v \in V$ and $V$ is closed under addiction. (This last step isn't formally necessay, it was just to make things clearer. If in the last step i wrote it's already clear to you that $u+v \in V$, then you are done.

Comment: So $u$ is actually the set begin defined, not an element of the set?  So I'm actually adding one copy of the set to another copy of the set?

Comment: what do you mean? you take $u$ and $v$ elements in your set $V$ (hence their specific form), then write their sum in an appropriate way... you just have to keep in mind that $u$ and $v$ are both pairs of elements (which was perhaps what got you confused when you tried to wrote $u+v$)

Comment: I understand now, thank you!